# Как убрать фокус в EditText при скрытии клавиатуры?

Tags: java, android

Если выбрать `EditText` то фокус будет на нем и появиться клава. Как сделать чтобы если я убрал клавиатуру то и фокус пропал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При нажатии на `EditText` устанавливаете флаг (true в boolean переменную).
2. Переопределяете нажатие кнопки назад (она закрывает клаву). В переопределённом слушателе проверяете эту переменную и перед вызовом `super.onBackPressed()` устанавливаете фокус в любой другой вью методом `View.requestFocus();`
3. Сохраняйте флаг из п.1 при повороте экрана.

Comment: А если я пролистаю список вниз. не закрывая клавиатуру, то фокус автоматически удалится вместе с 1 элементом и создатся в 10 элементе, это выглядит не красиво. Так что ваш вариант не подходит.

Может в манифесте какие то правки нужно с отображением клавиатуры сделать? Windows INput вроде

Comment: Вы можете в getVIew методе узнавать виден ли элемент списка с фокусом и если нет, то снимать с него фокус и тем самым скрывать клаву, например.

Comment: Не вариант, кнопку нужно нажимать два раза. Первый раз убирается клавиатура, второй раз фокус.